# pass a value from char array to BoS function in c

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I'm still struggling with my program that should print out characters in board of symbols.
The compiler says:

> char parameter is not compatible with type char*

Here is my code:

```
char characters[12] = {"ABCDEFGHIJ\0"};
char numbers[12] = {"0123456789\0"};

for (int vertical = 2; vertical<12; vertical++) {
    for (int horizontal = 1; horizontal<2; horizontal++) {
        text2(horizontal, vertical, numbers[horizontal]);
        color2(horizontal, vertical, BLUE);         
    }       
}

for (int abc = 170; abc < 180; abc++) {
    color(abc, BLUE);
    text(abc, characters[abc]);
}
```

It should actually print out only one character per pass.
here are both functions

```
void color2(int i, int j, int f) {
    sprintf_s(nachricht, ">># %d %d 0x%x\n", i, j, f);
    sendMessage( nachricht );
void text2(int i, int j, char* f) {
    sprintf_s(nachricht, ">>#T %d %d %s\n", i, j, f);
    sendMessage( nachricht );
}
```

color2 colors the fields and text2 shows charachters on fields
and here is the code of function sendMessage which is included in both mentioned functions

```
int sendMessage(char *sendbuf ) {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
        *ptr = NULL,
        hints;
    int iResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo("localhost", DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if ( iResult != 0 ) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for(ptr=result; ptr != NULL ;ptr=ptr->ai_next) {

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, 
            ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        if( verbose ) printf("socket connected\n");
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        terminate("Unable to connect to server!\n");
    }

    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send( ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    if( verbose ) printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    answer[0] = '\0';
    // Receive until the peer closes the connection
    do {


        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if ( iResult > 0 ) {
            recvbuf[iResult] = '\0';
            if( verbose ) printf("Bytes received: %d %s\n", iResult, recvbuf);
            strcat_s( answer, recvbuf );
            //printf(">>>%s<<<\n", answer );
        } else if ( iResult == 0 ) {
            if( verbose ) printf("Connection closed\n");
        } else
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    } while( iResult > 0 );

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the prototype of text2? Also you'll get runtime error because of the `text(abc, characters[abc]);`.

Comment: yes , it's a header file by the way, the code is: void color2(int i, int j, int f); and void text2(int i, int j, char* f);

Comment: `numbers[horizontal]` is char, but you are trying to pass it as char*. change your text2's last parameter to char f.

Comment: You don't need to put `\0` at the end of a string literal, it's done automatically.

Comment: I suspect `text2` expects the third argument to be a string, not a single character.

Comment: @Sparkm4n There's probably another function in the API that you can use to display a single character at a position, instead of a string of text. Look for a function name like `char2`.

Comment: Can you post a link to the documentation of this API?

Comment: It's a shame that the compiler you're using doesn't tell you the line number with the problem, or even the function where the issue lies...

Comment: There appear to be 2 possible sources for the error: `text2(horizontal, vertical, numbers[horizontal]);` and `text(abc, characters[abc]);`. Unless you can provide the prototypes or definitions for both functions, all anyone can do it guess at what the problem is. That said, I suspect that @Barmar is correct in the assessment that the function throwing the error is expecting a string and not a character. Please see: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dereference your pointer. Presumably in one of the functions you are calling, probably in text2() or text(). Can't tell you more without knowing more about the specifications of the functions.